# Using set_index within a custom function

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to convert the date observations from a column into the index for my dataframe. I am able to do this with the code below:

Sample data:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'Values':[1,2,3], 'Date':["1/1/2016 17:49","1/2/2016 7:10","1/3/2016 15:19"]})
```

Indexing code:

```
test['Date Index'] = pd.to_datetime(test['Date'])
test = test.set_index('Date Index')
test['Index'] = test.index.date
```

However when I try to include this code in a function, I am able to create the 'Date Index' column but `set_index` does not seem to work as expected.

```
def  date_index(df):
     df['Date Index'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
     df = df.set_index('Date Index')
     df['Index'] = df.index.date
```

If I inspect the output of not using a function `info()` returns:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 3 entries, 2016-01-01 17:49:00 to 2016-01-03 15:19:00
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Date      3 non-null object
Values    3 non-null int64
Index     3 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 96.0+ bytes
```

If I inspect the output of the function `info()` returns:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Date      3 non-null object
Values    3 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 120.0+ bytes
```

I would like the `DatetimeIndex`.

How can `set_index` be used within a function? Am I using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC `return df` is missing:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Values':[1,2,3], 'Exam Completed Date':["1/1/2016 17:49","1/2/2016 7:10","1/3/2016 15:19"]})

def  date_index(df):
     df['Exam Completed Date Index'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Exam Completed Date'])
     df = df.set_index('Exam Completed Date Index')
     df['Index'] = df.index.date
     return df

print (date_index(df1))
                          Exam Completed Date  Values       Index
Exam Completed Date Index                                        
2016-01-01 17:49:00            1/1/2016 17:49       1  2016-01-01
2016-01-02 07:10:00             1/2/2016 7:10       2  2016-01-02
2016-01-03 15:19:00            1/3/2016 15:19       3  2016-01-03
```

---

```
print (date_index(df1).info())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 3 entries, 2016-01-01 17:49:00 to 2016-01-03 15:19:00
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Exam Completed Date    3 non-null object
Values                 3 non-null int64
Index                  3 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 96.0+ bytes
None
```

Comment: The output of `test.info()` is different when using the function. I would like a DatetimeIndex. See edits to question.

Comment: Interesting, for me it works nice. please check edit.

Comment: The difference in your output is you have employed  `date_index(df1).info()` where I am using `df1.info()`. I think the distinction is important because I ultimately use `df1.index.values` on the dataframe which gives a different result if you use the custom `date_index()` function.